# Migrating domain controller to a new hardware

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm having a problem upgrading the hardware of my domain controller.
We have a Windows 2012 Domain controller (that is the only one DC in the network).
We wanted to change hardware to a newer one, so we bought a new Server with Windows 2012 R2.
I've run adprep /forestprep and adprep /domainprep on the old server (using the 2012 R2 DVD).
I've add the AD and DNS role on the new server, and added to the domain.

I've made the new server the Primary Domain Controller.
Now if I run: **netdom query fsmo** I see the new server in every list.

I've removed the old server from the Global Catalog and changed the DNS on every pc to the new server.

The problem is that every pc (and the new server as well) are still logging in to the ols server.
If I shutdown the old server it seems there are a lot of problems and Users cannot be found or authenticated (for example on TeamFoundation Server or SqlServers).

When I try to demote the old server it says that it cannot find other domains controllers on the network.
On the old servers however the new server is listed on the domain controllers list.

How can I make the new server the one and only domain server so I can dismiss the old server?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Even a brand new machine, installed after the migration, when added to the domain it logs in on the old server. While the netdom query fsmo gives the new machine for everything.

Comment: Did you do DCPROMO on the old one and promote the new machine to a Global Catalogue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after hours of research I did find a solution.
Everything was correct, the problem was not on the new promoted domain controller.
The problem was on the old domain controller, that for some reason stopped the replication services.

I solved using the following command on the old server:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoftdfs path dfsrVolumeConfig where volumeGuid="<GUID>" call ResumeReplication
```

Where the GUID is the one I found on the dcdiag /v output

After this the new domain controller replicated correctly, and I was able to safely demote the old server.